# Why does asserting on the result of Deref::deref fail with a type mismatch?

Tags: pointers, rust

The following is the [`Deref` example from *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html) except I've added another assertion.

Why does the `assert_eq` with the `deref` also equal `'a'`? Why do I need a `*` once I've manually called `deref`?

```
use std::ops::Deref;

struct DerefExample<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<T> Deref for DerefExample<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = DerefExample { value: 'a' };
    assert_eq!('a', *x.deref()); // this is true
    // assert_eq!('a', x.deref()); // this is a compile error
    assert_eq!('a', *x); // this is also true
    println!("ok");
}
```

If I uncomment the line, I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
18 |     assert_eq!('a', x.deref());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected char, found &char
   |
   = note: expected type `char`
              found type `&char`
   = help: here are some functions which might fulfill your needs:
           - .to_ascii_lowercase()
           - .to_ascii_uppercase()
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let's spell out the generic types for your specific example: `'a'` is `char`, so we have:

```
impl Deref for DerefExample<char> {
    type Target = char;

    fn deref(&self) -> &char {
        &self.value
    }
}
```

Notably, the return type of `deref` is a *reference* to a `char`. Thus it shouldn't be surprising that, when you use just `x.deref()`, the result is a `&char` rather than a `char`. Remember, at that point `deref` is just another normal method — it's just implicitly invoked as *part* of some language-provided special syntax. `*x`, for example, will call `deref` and dereference the result, when applicable. `x.char_method()` and `fn_taking_char(&x)` will also call `deref` some number of times and then do something further with the result.

Why does `deref` return a reference to begin with, you ask? Isn't that circular? Well, no, it isn't circular: it *reduces* library-defined smart pointers to the built-in type `&T` which the compiler already knows how to dereference. By returning a reference instead of a value, you avoid a copy/move (which may not always be possible!) and allow `&*x` (or `&x` when it's coerced) to refer to the *actual* `char` that `DerefExample` holds rather than a temporary copy.

See also:

- [Why is the return type of Deref::deref itself a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624743/155423)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "*x, for example, will call deref and dereference the result" I take it you mean literally two things are occurring, first a call to deref to get a (&) reference, then 'dereferencing' that to gain access to the char.