# Recursive `Box`ed enum variants

Tags: enums, rust

I have an enum `Expr`:

```rust
enum Expr {
    Const(i32),
    Add {
        lhs: Expr,
        rhs: Expr,
    },
}
```

If I compile this, I get the error telling me that I have recursive types without indirection. There are at least two ways of adding indirection:

1. `Box`ing each field in `Expr::Add`:

   ```rust
   Add {
       lhs: Box<Expr>,
       rhs: Box<Expr>,
   }
   ```
2. Extracting `Expr::Add` to a separate struct and then `Box`ing it in the enum variant:

   ```rust
   struct ExprAdd {
       lhs: Expr,
       rhs: Expr,
   }

   enum Expr {
       Const(i32),
       Add(Box<ExprAdd>),
   }
   ```

**The first** way of doing things introduces excessive `Box`ing. That is, the number of `Box`es is equal to the number of fields in the `Expr::Add` variant and instantiating `Expr::Add` is verbose:

```rust
let e = Expr::Add { 
    lhs: Box::new(Expr::Const(1)),
    rhs: Box::new(Expr::Const(2)),
};
```

However, it allows for convenient pattern matching:

```rust
let e = Expr::Const(1);
match e {
    Expr::Const(c) => {}
    // Convenient destructuring.
    Expr::Add { lhs, rhs } => {}
}
```

**The second** way of doing things is more efficient due to the usage of only one `Box` but it is unnecessarily verbose(`ExprAdd` struct is not really needed here) and pattern matching is limited:

```rust
let e = Expr::Const(1);
match e {
    Expr::Const(c) => {}
    // No convenient destructuring.
    // `expr` is of type `ExprAdd`.
    // Expr::Add(Box(ExprAdd { lhs, rhs })) => {} // fails because `Box` has private members.
    Expr::Add(expr) => { /* use `expr.lhs` and `expr.rhs` */ }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Which is better? Which is more idiomatic?
2. Is there a way of declaring a recursive enum like in the **second** example that allows convenient pattern matching like in the **first** example?

Comment: On nightly you could activate box patterns, but you're probably not on nightly.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is it impossible to have a nested match on a recursive datatype that uses a smart pointer like a Box, Rc, or Arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48246510/155423); [How to pattern match a Box to get a struct's attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52398060); [How to pattern match on values inside a type implementing Deref, such as Box, without copying the contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53132035). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.